# Programming a PIC microcontroller using toggle switches and logic gates. Ideas to suggest?

Tags: microcontroller, logic-gates, programming

**I saw a guy on Youtube  programming an EEPROM using toggle switches and he would press a button to send a clock to the EEPROM for the data to be written.  Could I do the  same thing  to program  a  microcontroller?**  [image]

Above is an manual EEPROM  programmer I got  from the  web.

have a nice day.

Comment: I used to do that in hexadecimal-40 years ago.

Comment: @Sparky256 You mean programming the  EPROM/EEPROM using a hexadecimal keypad?

Comment: Yes, you could program a microcontroller using toggle switches and logic gates.

Comment: Yes. A Standalone programmer with hexadecimal switch inputs. Each digit was 1 nibble or 4 bits.

Comment: But I only programmed about 1 KB that way. Very tedious and easy to make mistakes.

Comment: @immibis would I need a specific  clock depending on the microcontroller, I guess?

Comment: @Sparky256 if you have the time, if you know of any , could you suggest some source which I could  rely on?

Comment: @JardelB. I've made my own PIC12F508 programmer using an Arduino. The protocol is quite simple (although not well documented at all!) and not at all dependent on timing. The programmer supplies the clock, it would be one of your toggle switches (with debouncing).

Comment: just read the documentation for the various mcus out there, some interfaces have specific timing so that wouldnt work but others the timing could probably tolerate human speed...Its not parallel though like the DEC PDP days, you could certainly build something that sits in front of an mcu that is PDP like...you could just play with a pdp simulator pdp-8, pdp11, etc...

Comment: Memories of boot strapping PDP-11's, circa mid-70's.  Anything can be done, but why.  What would be your learning goal.  So any program would have to be small, so you can enter it without making mistakes.  The internet is full of people, who have no sense.  Take the higher road.

Comment: Shivers [PDP-11/40](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iIsZVqhaneo).

Answer (score 4):

Since the PIC MCUs accept serial data and time their own writes (the relatively modern ones such as [16F628](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/41196g.pdf), anyway) you could get by with only a few switches, one of which would have to be debounced.

It would be extraordinarily unpleasant, error-prone, and a total waste of time.

Comment: I really  find it more fun this way than just  do it the "easy" way. That's just my opinion.